# Array of Hashes Mongoid with Rails 4

Tags: mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4

How to define a model for mongodb in rails such that a field contains array of hashes and we can easily querying inside that array list. I am using mongoid gem with Rails 4.

I just want the document should be like..

```
params =  { 
            "type" : String,
            "user_id" : Integer,
            "date" : Date (UTC),
            "values" : [    
                { "value": Integer, "created_at": DateTime},
                { "value": Integer, "created_at": DateTime},
                { "value": Integer, "created_at": DateTime}
            ]
        }
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you should check out `embedded document`. With `Mongoid` and `Rails`:

```
class Something
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :type
  field :user_id, type: Integer
  field :date, type: Date

  embeds_many :values
end

class Value
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps::Created

  field :value, type: Integer
  embedded_in :something
end
```

With these two classes, `Something` will have many `values` which you can query easily. This is not actually an array of hashes but I think it would help you or at least give you an option.

Comment: thanks @vutran. Please check the updated question for the document type I want to build. Thanks

Comment: Updated my answer, it's basically the same thing but I changed a bit so it would match your need.

Comment: Thanks will have a look and try whether this suits for my app requirements or not.. Thanks.